# Postfix TLS connection timeout

Tags: server, email, postfix, ssl, mail

If this is the wrong forum for this question, please let me know

I have a home Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server thats been working correctly for a few months now, but sometime in the past two weeks its stopped being able to send out emails anymore from php. I'm fairly inexperienced in Linux, so I might have missed something obvious, but after 5 hours of troubleshooting I decided its time to ask for help, so: please help?!

Mail Transfer Agent: Postfix running as a relay to Zoho using TLS on port 587 Running at home, ISP (Verizon) blocks port 25

trying to send test messages with php AND in terminal with the mail command, same result with both.

my domin: greenmatter.us

It seems like I'm not able to establish the encrypted connection with them, but I'm not sure why since I haven't changed anything since the last time it was working. If anybody could point me down the right path, I'd greatly appreciate it (some of the things I've tried already below)

mail log snipit: Oct 31 17:26:23 greenmatter postfix/qmgr[1998]: EAB633C7E: from=, size=381, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Oct 31 17:26:53 greenmatter postfix/smtp[3118]: connect to smtp.zoho.com[165.254.168.48]:587: Connection timed out

Oct 31 17:26:53 greenmatter postfix/smtp[3118]: EAB633C7E: to=, relay=none, delay=6906, delays=6876/0.05/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp.zoho.com[165.254.168.48]:587: Connection timed out)

If I run openssl s_client -connect smtp.zoho.com:587 it hangs and eventually outputs: connect: Connection timed out connect:errno=110

If I run openssl s_client -connect greenmatter.us:587 it outputs: connect: Connection refused connect:errno=111

If I run openssl s_client -connect greenmatter.us:587 -servername greenmatter.us -showcerts | openssl x509 -text -noout it outputs: connect:errno=111 unable to load certificate 139754715526816:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: Does `telnet smtp.zoho.com 587` give you some lines ending with `220 mx.zohomail.com SMTP Server ready October 31, 2016 3:29:53 PM PDT`? (To get out, type `QUIT`). If not then the most likely cause is that`smtp.zoho.com` is blocking your IP address.

Comment: Also with questions like this you might find that looking at the answers on http://serverfault.com/ or perhaps asking for help there may yield better results. Since postfix isn't Ubuntu specific so you would perhaps find a larger pool of relevant resources to draw on there.

Comment: Well, I have to assume it was them blocking me like zwets said.  I sent Zoho an email asking if my configuration was correct, and (without a response), the emails magically all sent a day later.  Thanks